# Multiple usercontrol not reflected while setting DataTemplate to ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I am trying to add two usercontrols in one view

1. usercontrol working fine which get call in constructor i am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for 'SelectedViewModel'.

property get updated for second usercontrol but not reflected in view . 
thanks in advance

```
<Window x:Class="MovieBookinGWithUserControl.View.StartupWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MovieBookinGWithUserControl.ViewModel"
           xmlns:localview ="clr-namespace:MovieBookinGWithUserControl.View" 
        Title="StartupWindow" Height="AUTo" Width="Auto">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate   DataType="{x:Type local:LoginWIndowViewModel}">
            <localview:LoginWindow></localview:LoginWindow>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:MovieInfoViewModel }">
            <localview:MovieInfo ></localview:MovieInfo>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <StackPanel x:Name="navigation" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="Auto">              
            </StackPanel>
            <ContentControl x:Name="Pages" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you sure the Binding is being correctly updated? Though this may be the typical behavior, for all I know... I'm not aware of whether the ContentTemplate should update itself automatically if the Content changes, or not.

Comment: If not, you could always use a custom `ContentTemplateSelector` class.

Comment: I've tried your code with a simple example, and it appears to work fine. Could you add your ViewModel code here, and the code that updates the SelectedViewModel property? There's nothing wrong with the XAML that I can see.